# Passing cell values as parameters to ExcelDNA UDF

Tags: .net, excel, excel-dna

So I have a custom function I developed in ExcelDNA and have it loaded up in Excel. It works fine when I type in parameters as strings and call the function, however, when I put those strings into cells and then pass them in by referencing the cell, it fails. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Example:

If I type this into a cell: `=GetDiscountFactor("USD", "EUR", "11/01/2011", "11/01/2011 16:00", "Bid")`

It works - but this: `=GetDiscountFactor(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2)` fails, even though those cells are pointing to values that are identical to the ones I can type in.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your function expecting a date or a string?
It would help if you could post a simple function and some parameter values that recreates the problem you see. Your function might be failing because it is throwing an unhandled exception when Excel passes you unexpected data due to formatting you've applied to those cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably referencing the date/times as double or date. Change the parameters in your function to objects instead. E.g.,

```
Public Function GetDiscountFactor(byval sUSD As String, ByVal sEUR As String _
  , ByVal oDate1 As Object, ByVal oDate2 As Object, ByVal sBid As String)
```

You can check to see what type of variable it is later in your code.